# C# label text stuck

Tags: c#, function, label

i have been training on making classes and inheritances. now i'm facing a problem printbase method doesn't work  on my code, the label text doesn't change what is the mistake i did ?
they way how this code works is the method new dog creates a new dog with a name based on a combobox item so it uses it's name and generates number and summons certain method called bark, and it should we i click the button it calls the method print base and change the text of the labels but it doesn't work. any ideas ?

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    class animal : Form1
    {
        public string name;
        public int age;
        public string action;
        public void printbase(string whatname, int whatage, string whataction)
        {
            namelabel.Text = whatname;
            agelabel.Text = whatage.ToString();
            actionlabel.Text = whataction;
        }
    }
    class dog : animal
    {
        public string dogaction;
        public void bark()
        {
            dogaction = "wuff";
        }

        public void newdog()
        {              
            Random x = new Random();             
            string names;
            names = dogscombo.Text;
            dog hey = new dog();
            hey.name = names;
            hey.age = x.Next(1,10);
            bark();
            hey.action = dogaction;
            printbase(hey.name, hey.age, hey.action);

        }
    }

    public Form1() 
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
    }          
    private void getbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        switch (dogscombo.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case (0):
                dog u = new dog();
                u.newdog();                                 
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your class names are confusing, but since you're making a *new* dog (form), your changes aren't applied to the form you're viewing

Answer (score 0):

You should create independed class animal than inherit from it class dog.
In your case, class animal is based on the class Form1. So the programm creates new Form but doesn't show it to user.
If you don`t intend to create new form, don`t use class Form1 a base class for class animal. If you do intend, than call method to show newly created form to user.
This code will work:

```
    private void getbutton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        switch (dogscombo.SelectedIndex)
        {
            case (1):
                dog u = new dog();
                u.newdog();
                u.Show();
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: i had to link class animal with form 1 to be able to use the combobox and labels.

Comment: OK, I added some code, now it will work. Add this little modifications

Comment: Pay attention that only one choice from combo is handled in your code

Comment: worked but it generates a new form so i have 2 forms when i click the button, by the way the case doesnt have to be 1 , 0 have a value in the index

Comment: Sure, second form will emerge according to your code. Wasn`t it intentional?